# Gaussian Processes with GPytorch - More output than input data

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gaussian-process

I am following the basic tutorial https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/stable/examples/01_Exact_GPs/Simple_GP_Regression.html to train a Gaussian Process for the following data

```
train_x is a tensor of [4058, 12]
train_y is a tensor of [4058, 140]
```

I get an error calculating the loss

```
loss = -mll(output, train_y)
```

saying that `output` (model(train_x)) and `train_y` don't have the same dimension. Given this, I tried `MultitaskGPModel` https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/stable/examples/03_Multitask_Exact_GPs/Multitask_GP_Regression.html getting a very similar error

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (568120) must match the size of tensor b (8116) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

Apparently `MultitaskGPModel` requires the same total number of entries to be equal. Is there a way to train a multiple-entry GP?

Comment: Has anyone trained a GP with more outputs than inputs?